# merging data frames over multiple columns

Tags: r, merge, vlookup

I have two different data frames with 5 columns and all these columns should be cross-checked in order to find a match, I tried with merge but I need help cuz the answer isn't what I want.

```
[businessunitid oenace_code turnover    n_employee  age NACE
1689327 01.5        1   6   015
1375743 01.6                016
1233048 01.6    45000   1   36  016
1229784 01.6    120000  1   26  016
1224677 01.6    80000   1   9   016
1219526 01.6        1   9   016
1230104 56      3   8   56
1371674 01.00-0 25000   2   8   0100][1]
```

have two data frames of this kind

```
ALLDATA_small <- merge(ATDATA_small, ATDATA_origin_new_small, by.x ="NACE" , all=TRUE)
```

I don't want to merge them just over NACE but all the 5 factors one after the other should be checked.

Comment: Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242350/merging-on-multiple-columns-r

Comment: i dont want a full joint..i want to have an inner join and not just over x and y but over nace and employee class and age ,etc.

Comment: NACE KLASSE EMPLOYEE CLASS LEGAL FORM AGE CLASS
0120 3 02_ 3-10 employees Societa di Persone 02_7-10 years
0119 4 02_ 3-10 employees Societa di Capitali 02_7-10 years
0149 2 01_ <=2 employees Societa di Persone 04_ >20 years
0123 1 02_ 3-10 employees Societa di Capitali 02_7-10 years